# Inheritance and overriding Concept :methods call

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to understand the object reference created in SuperClass and SubClass. I read a lot online but still not able to figure out which reference is called.
Here is my code.

```
public class X {
    public void xCall() {
        System.out.println("X method called");
    }

    public void move(){
      System.out.println("I'm in parent class");
   }
}

public class Y extends X{

    public void yCall() {
        System.out.println("Y method called");
    }

    public void move(){
      System.out.println("I'm in child class");
   }
}
```

I tried to making following objects and got the result as shown.

```
    X a = new X();
    X b = new Y();

    a.move();// runs the method in X class

    b.move();//Runs the method in Y class
```

Output :

```
I'm in parent class
I'm in child class
```

**My question is why**

```
 b.move();
```

**is giving output**

```
`I'm in child class`
```

**instead of**

```
`I'm in parent class`
```

**My question is different from the one marked as duplicate of. As I understand that it will refer the superclass not the subclass. My question is then why is it giving me the result of method in the subclass?**

Comment: Don't mix compile-time behavior with runtime behavior.

Comment: @manouti I'm clear about compile time error and runtime error. I just mentioned it there to tell when I'm writing `b.yCall()` its not accepting it. Its giving me error there itself.

Comment: b.move() execute before b.yCall(), so it displays the result in runtime. Of course you can not compile this code because not found method

Comment: This is an exact duplicate. Methods are resolved at compile time based on the reference expression used to invoke them.  `b` is of type `X`. `X` does not declare a method named `yCall`. The rest is polymorphism and late binding and is unrelated.

Comment: The first line of the accepted answer: _When you declare a variable as having the type of the superclass, you can only access (public) methods and member variables of the superclass through that variable._

Comment: That's just a way to explain what I'm trying to ask. Please don't misinterpret. I know It will not find the method `yCall` as it is a reference to class `X` but my problem is why is it reading `move()` from class `Y` instead of class `X`?

Comment: That's polymorphism. That's runtime late-binding. That's the whole point of Object Oriented languages.

Comment: And you also state _This is overriding. I understood._ So I'm not misinterpreting anything. You seem to understand what's happening for that case.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the content may be the same. But my question is different. What solution I'm asking for is not given in that question.

Comment: The answer is there, right in the accepted answer. Cast your expression to the appropriate subtype to have access to its methods. `((Y)b).yCall()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Again I repeat why `b.move()` reads `Y's move()` method rather than `X's move()` method.

Comment: Yah you earlier said you understand why. `b`  is referencing an object of type `Y`. So which one is it. Your question is very confusing. You've changed it twice now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I understand why `yCall` cannot be refered through `b`..As b is reference of `X` and not `Y`. I just dont understand why `b.move()` is going in Y's move() not X's move().

Comment: What are you referring to when you say _This is overriding. I understood._?

Comment: Also `b.yCall();` doesn't give you any output as it won't compile. Your question currently makes no sense. Please clarify it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I modified my question to make to it clear what i want to ask.

Comment: Ok. Now your question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840080/how-does-inheritance-and-polymorphism-work-in-this-situation), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391915/late-binding-in-java), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809274/java-polymorphism-late-binding-rules), or any of hundreds of similar questions on Stack Overflow. The concept behind all this is the basis of all Java and would be covered in any tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

Your `move` method is part of the `X` class, while `yCall` is not.

You're telling in your code that you have a `b` Object of type `X`, so there is no way to call a method on it, which is not a method from `X` or from one of its parent classes.

You would have to cast it to an `Y` object .

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. When I'm not aloud to call method `yCall` using `b` then how come I'm getting result of method `move` from class `Y` rather than class `X`?